# Disadvantages of MySQL Row Locking

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rabbitmq

I am using row locking (transactions) in MySQL for creating a job queue. Engine used is InnoDB.

**SQL Query**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE status IS NULL 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 
FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE mytable SET status = 1;
COMMIT;
```

According to this [webpage](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/),

> `The problem with SELECT FOR UPDATE is that it usually creates a
>   single synchronization point for all of the worker processes, and you
>   see a lot of processes waiting for the locks to be released with
>   COMMIT.`

**Question:** Does this mean that when the first query is executed, which takes some time to finish the transaction before, when the second similar query occurs before the first transaction is committed, it will have to wait for it to finish before the query is executed? If this is true, then I do not understand why the row locking of a single row (which I assume) will affect the next transaction query that would not require reading that locked row?

Additionally, can this problem be solved (and still achieve the effect row locking does for a job queue) by doing a `UPDATE` instead of the transaction?

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 1
WHERE status IS NULL
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Locking is based on the storage engine - what are you using?

Comment: Thanks (and 9 more chars to go)

Comment: Unfortunately, your `status IS NULL ORDER BY` query guarantees a full table scan of `mytable.`  Indexes aren't helpful for IS NULL searches. If you could refactor your code to eliminate NULL status values, search for some other value, and use an index for that, you'd save a lot of table-scan time.

Comment: Will setting the default value of `status` to `0` and indexing it be better?

Comment: Yes, that scheme will make your 'find the next mytable row that's eligible for processing' operation much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use FOR `UPDATE` with a storage engine that uses page or row locks, rows examined by the query are write-locked until the end of the current transaction. Using `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` sets a shared lock that permits other transactions to read the examined rows but not to `update or delete` them.
and about this query

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 1
WHERE status IS NULL
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

since innodb

automatically acquire locks during the processing of SQL statements i think it works as the same .